# Batch file to insert Excel data into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, excel, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that takes information from an Excel spreadsheet and adds new rows into my SQL Server.

I think what I have currently is nearly there. As it runs and says a line has been updated, but it hasn't.

This is my batch file:

```
@echo off

copy \\RDS-2012-C\2012_N_Drive\Operations\Reports\Metrics\sql2.xlsx C:\ACCESS_SQLSVR\import_location
sqlcmd -S RDS-2012-G\RDS_SQL -d Master -i C:\ACCESS_SQLSVR\import_location\sesame_import.sql

pause
```

And this is what it runs:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1;
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1;
GO

EXEC sp_MSSet_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1;
GO

SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\ACCESS_SQLSVR\import_location\sql2.xlsx;HDR=YES;IMEX=1',
'SELECT * FROM [SQL$]')
GO
```

Do I simply need a different command instead of `SELECT`?

Also, the full database and table in the SQL Server is called:

```
Sesame_FTest.dbo.SQL
```

Running this when the table doesn't exist results in the table being created and filled with the Excel information. But running it a second time with a new Excel doesn't update like I thought it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this . . .

```
------ INSERT INTO NON-EXISTING TABLES

USE [YourDatabase]
GO

SELECT * INTO tbl_Mapping
FROM   OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
       'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\Users\rshuell001\Desktop\State Street\Final Deliverables\Raw Data\Mapping.xlsx',
       'SELECT * FROM [Mapping$]')

SELECT * INTO tbl_Data
FROM   OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
       'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\Users\rshuell001\Desktop\State Street\Final Deliverables\Raw Data\Data.xlsx',
       'SELECT * FROM [Data$]')
```

OR . . .

```
------ INSERT INTO EXISTING TABLES

USE [YourDatabase]
GO
Insert INTO tbl_Mapping
SELECT * FROM   OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
       'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\Users\rshuell001\Desktop\State Street\Final Deliverables\Raw Data\Mapping.xlsx',
       'SELECT * FROM [Mapping$]')


Insert INTO tbl_Data
SELECT * FROM   OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
       'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\Users\rshuell001\Desktop\State Street\Final Deliverables\Raw Data\Data.xlsx',
       'SELECT * FROM [Data$]')
```